# Max power draw on voltage rails of mini PCIe Card

Tags: power, pcie

I am designing a custom mini PCIe card.  What is the max power I can draw from the 1v5 rail, and the 3v3 rail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document your looking for is called **PCI EXPRESS MINI CARD ELECTROMECHANICAL SPECIFICATION**. You can find the PDF on the homepage of the PCI-SIG if you are a member or on your favorite search engine. The most recent revision seems to be 2.1.

In the older version 1.2 I have on hand, it says in 3.4.3 Power:

- 1100 mA (2750 mA) normal (peak) current on 3.3V
- 375 mA (500mA) normal (peak) current on 1.5V